# SCSS syntax highlighting in VS2010 without Mindscape?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, sass

I'm looking to use Sass (SCSS syntax) for my CSS files in a VisualStudio 2010 project, and need syntax highlighting for it. Everything I've found keeps directing me to the Mindscape extension, but the nagger for upgrading is distracting and is a game-killer for it.

Is there a way to get SCSS syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2010 without using the Mindscape extension?

Comment: The upgrade window doesn't bother me nearly as much as the fact that it is sloooooooooowwww.  It seems to re-render the highlighting after each key stroke, and this becomes unusable if you have very large scss files or you are importing several files.  You may literally have to wait 4 or 5 seconds for the highlighting to render after a single key entry.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but have you checked out the [web essentials plugin for visual studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f)?  This has great support for scss.

Comment: I already have it installed and it doesn't recognize my SCSS files at all.

Comment: Web Essentials doesn't do scss, only less.

Comment: Web essentials used to do SCSS (in a limited way), but they dropped support in version 2.7. Currently [the SASS/SCSS support feature request](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3140436-support-for-sass-scss) is the most popular request on their UserVoice page (go vote!).

Comment: This is now included in VS2013 Update 2 CTP 2.  I don't think that helps us 2010 ppl, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: SassyStudio -- "Provides some support for sass files in visual studio"

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: It's for 2012/2013, not 2010, but it looks promising. I'll have to take a look at it next time I'm working on a Sass/.net project.